# Openshift scaling on specific (software) condition

Tags: openshift, scaling, openstack

I'm looking for a scaling mechanism on OpenStack cloud, and then I found OpenShift. My scenario is something like this: we have a distributed system with many agents stand on many nodes. One node contain a Message Broker that direct the traffic. We want to monitor the Message Broker node, if a queue is full, we scale out the agent nodes handle that queue. In brief, we monitor one node to scale other nodes.

We used OpenStack cloud now. In OpenStack, I found heat and ceilometer which are able to create alarm and scale out nodes. However, alarms are based only on general info like CPU, RAM, Network usage, etc (not inside-VM info).

Then I search for a layer above: PaaS. I found OpenShift can handle scaling apps. But as I knew, the scaling mechanism of OpenShift is: duplicate the apps based on network traffic, then put an HAProxy in front.

Am I right that OpenShift can't monitor software specific data. Is there any other tool that suit our scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this script (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-haproxy/usr/bin/haproxy_ctld.rb) to control how your gears are scaled, but I believe that it is still experimental.  Make sure that you read through all of the comments and understand what you are doing before making any changes.  You might also consider spinning up a second scaled application to test this on before messing with your production application.